# MongoDB: how to search for fields in a collection

Tags: mongodb, field

How do I find a list of fields in a db?  `db.collection.find()` shows all the data, but I would just like a list of the fields so I can set up a CSV export.

Comment: that was asked in 2010.  has a mongodb method been developed?

Comment: No, the answers to that question are still relevant. What you are trying to do (turn a collection into a table) is quite against the philosophy of MongoDB, so don't expect native support for it soon.

Comment: @Philipp i'm trying to get a list of fields so I can export the data to a csv file.  I don't always remember what the keys are in every collection and I'd love to just see a list.

Comment: @dwstein findAll() return you a DBCursor. You can loop on it and create a list of Map<String, String> that you export to CSV. 
while (dbCursor.hasNext()) { dataMapList.add(dbCursor.next().toMap()); }